# Django forms for filtering search results?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, web-deployment

I want to add some checkbox filters to a car sales website. 
My model categories to filter by are 'Brand', 'Model', and 'Price'.
Within django what would be the best method to create a search function based on the above?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are looking for a third party package, you should use [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter).

Comment: Looks good. Thanks